# Define and trigger a custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the need to call a custom event on my DatatTble's cells. So, I have the following method:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.longClick = function (callback) {
    //event
  };
})(jQuery);
```

To make the binding, as a test, I do the following:

```
$("h1").longClick(function () {
  console.log('triggered');
});
```

I need to replace my click event:

```
$('#dtStatus').on('click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
  console.log('triggered');
});
```

With my longpress event.

```
$('#dtStatus').on('longClick', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
  console.log('triggered');
});
```

The `h1` longclick and `td` click event work, but the td `longpress` doesn't.
Can some one tell me why I can't use my event like `on('longClick')`?

Thank you.

Comment: For `on('longClick')` to work you need to be using `trigger('longClick')` somewhere in your code. Are you doing that?

Comment: In your case `longClick` is not an event, it is a plugin(unless you are using the `trigger()` method to trigger the `longClick` event within the plugin

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No, I'm not doing that. Sorry, but I'm having trouble undestranding the purpose of `trigger('longClick')`. Can you please give me some more details?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, Thank you for your answare. I'm not familiar with the use of `trigger()`. I've some searching to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are mixing up functions with events. With `$.fn.longClick` you created a function that you already called successfully with `$("h1").longClick(...)`.

Now, to use it like an event, you need to trigger it first. For example:

```
$('#dtStatus').click(function() {
    $(this).trigger("myEvent");
});
```

It triggers event with name `myEvent` on the item that was clicked. Then you can catch that event with:

```
$('#dtStatus').on("myEvent", function() {
    alert("myEvent called!");
});
```

You can read more about custom events in [jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/).